# Preg Pattern Finding

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to parse a html content that have something like this:

```
<td class="s3_40">12,909</td>
```

i tried many regex to find string in between (12,909)
like : `%<td class=\"s3_40\">(.*)</td>%`
but i didn't find that .

Comment: Someone will tell you...

Comment: You should stop trying to use regular expression for this and use an [XHTML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Regular expressions are not a very good tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: Regex can be used for extract content to some degree, if it's a one-time work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help:

```
$str = '<td class="s3_40">12,909</td>';
if (preg_match('#<td class="s3_40">(.*)</td>#s',  $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: i tested via [regexTester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm) but i didn't get any data

Comment: I tried on another [Regex Tester](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php) its works, i dont know why on [regexTester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm) doesnt work, maybe it caused by added semicolon: $ptn = "/<;td class="s3_40">;(.*)<;/td>;/";

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it with a regex. You can try a pattern like this:

```
/<td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#(?<=(s3_40">))([^<]+)(?=(</td>))#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this, just keep adding to s3_41, s3_42, etc to the class you need.

```
<?php
$s = '<td class="s3_40">12,909</td>';
$pat = '@<td class=".*(s3_40|s3_41).*".*?>(.*?)</td>@isU';
preg_match_all($pat,$s,$ms);
var_dump($ms);
```